# Windows Phone 8: How to play an audio file using MediaElement class ?

Tags: windows-phone-8, mediaelement

I am using MediaElement class and trying to play an audio file (.mp3) which I have added in the solution explorer (see the image below).

I am using the following code in the constructor

```
// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
    DataContext = App.ViewModel;

    MediaElement el = new MediaElement();
    el.Source = new Uri("horse.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    el.Play();
}
```

I have also added a screenshot below, just to give an idea of where the horse.mp3 file resides.

Please help me out on this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What's the Build Action on your MP3 file? For the URI format you've used it should be Build Action = Content.

Also, you didn't actually add the MediaElement to your page. MediaElement is a visual control that needs to be part of the visual tre in order to operate. If you're looking to do short sound effects on WP7/WP8 you should use XNA's SoundEffect. You'll have to pre-format your audio track very specifically but you'll get the benefit of it overlapping with the user's currently playing audio and not needing to add it to the visual tree.

Answer (score 0):

in xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="PlayFile"
            Click="PlayFile_Click_1"
            Content="Play mp3" />
```

and in code:

```
MediaElement MyMedia = new MediaElement();
// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(MyMedia);

    MyMedia.CurrentStateChanged += MyMedia_CurrentStateChanged;
    MyMedia.MediaEnded += MyMedia_MediaEnded;
}

void MyMedia_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ended event " + MyMedia.CurrentState.ToString());
    // Set the source to null, force a Close event in current state
    MyMedia.Source = null;
}

void MyMedia_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    switch (MyMedia.CurrentState)
    {
        case System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.AcquiringLicense:
            break;
        case System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Buffering:
            break;
        case System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Closed:
            break;
        case System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Individualizing:
            break;
        case System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Opening:
            break;
        case System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Paused:
            break;
        case System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Playing:
            break;
        case System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Stopped:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CurrentState event " + MyMedia.CurrentState.ToString());
}

private void PlayFile_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Play Awesome music file, stored as content in the Assets folder in your app
    MyMedia.Source = new Uri("Assets/AwesomeMusic.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    MyMedia.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add

```
el.AutoPlay=true
```

Hope this help.